# sum and calculate average in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, average

Assuming that I have a table like this

```
| id | name   | code | method | account | time | date       |
|----|--------|------|--------|---------|------|------------|
| 1  | name01 | 200  | GET    | 1       | 100  | 2020-06-10 |
| 2  | name01 | 201  | GET    | 2       | 150  | 2020-06-10 |
| 3  | name02 | 200  | POST   | 4       | 200  | 2020-06-10 |
| 4  | name01 | 200  | GET    | 5       | 250  | 2020-06-11 |
| 5  | name02 | 200  | POST   | 1       | 300  | 2020-06-11 |
```

How can I select an exact date range and get the sum of `account` and average of `time`?
Notice that same `name` but different `code` should be configured as different group.

e.g. select date range **2020-06-10** to **2020-06-11**

return:

```
| name   | code | method | account | time |
|--------|------|--------|---------|------|
| name01 | 200  | GET    | 6       | 175  |
| name01 | 201  | GET    | 2       | 150  |
| name02 | 200  | POST   | 5       | 250  |
```

And if I select the same day like this: **2020-06-10** to **2020-06-10**

just return:

```
| name   | code | method | account | time |
|--------|------|--------|---------|------|
| name01 | 200  | GET    | 1       | 100  |
| name01 | 201  | GET    | 2       | 150  |
| name02 | 200  | POST   | 4       | 200  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
select
    name,
    code,
    method,
    sum(account) account,
    avg(time) time
from mytable
where date between '2020-06-10' and '2020-06-11'
group by name, code, method
```